# Capture for Kinect Camera

Tags: kinect, opencv, openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks, that I have done, now I want to save the images I have listened to from to video using the video writer class,

```
VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
```

However,  I don't want to use the default camera (webcam), instead the kinect camera. I have tried -1, but still won't work.
So, If someone has opened a capture using KINECT camera, that would be great if they shared with me how they did it.
many thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10734/capture-for-kinect-camera/) by [robwa](https://answers.ros.org/users/751/robwa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-07-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-07-26**:
You might want to rewrite/reformat your post. It's a bit difficult to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, to open the kinect camera with OpenCV you need to use this:

VideoCapture capture( CV_CAP_OPENNI );

---

Originally posted by [DiogoCorrea](https://answers.ros.org/users/933/diogocorrea/) with karma: 61 on 2011-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2